# I need help accessing a button inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to update the value attribute of a button inside a table cell.

I'm iteration over each cell and my code looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0, cell; cell = table.cells[i]; i++) {                            
    $(cell).find('.btn btn-default').val("new value");                  
}
```

But this doesn't work.

My 'cell' looks like this:

```
<div class=\"list-element\">
<a class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-link\" href=\"www.somelink\"></a>
<input class=\"btn btn-default\" type=\"button\" value=\"some stuff\">
<label class=\"label label-success\">stuff</label>
</div>
```

So i want to change "some stuff".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.find('.btn.btn-default')`

Comment: You should an Id to your button and find it by Id.

Comment: And a bit more info following @Satpal comment - you you are currently looking for is an element with the `.btn` class that has the element `<btn-default>` inside it (`<button class="btn"> <btn-default>...</btn-default></button>` doesn't really makes sense, right?). If you want to target element by multiple classes you should use `.class1.class2.class3`

Comment: @KevinKloet, read the other comments... and check your code before posting (because it's wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
   for (var i = 0, cell; cell = table.cells[i]; i++) {                            
            $(cell).find('.btn.btn-default').val("new value");                  
        }
```

Remove space in find method

Answer (score 1):

```
   for(var i = 0, cell; cell = table.cells[i]; i++) {                            
        $(cell).find('.btn .btn-default').val("new value");                  
    }
```